# Is it true that $|a-b|<t \Longrightarrow |a|<|b|+t$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a$,$b \in \mathbb{R}$ be two real numbers and let $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$ a real positive number.

I would like to know if is it true that

$$
|a-b|<t
\Longrightarrow
|a|<|b|+t
$$

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MartinR thanks, but i haven't found it

Comment: @MateyMath: There is a great tool [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) where you can enter a math formula and it is searched on MSE, see also [Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange). – In your case: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Ca-b%7C%3Ct%20%5CLongrightarrow%20%7Ca%7C%3C%7Cb%7C%2Bt%24&p=1.

Comment: thanks but @MartinR should I close this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because by the triangle inequlity
$$ ||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$$
and of course $|a|-|b|\leq ||a|-|b||$.